# How can I force a Xamarin Forms iOS label to match height of its parent ScrollView?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, scrollview

I have a Label inside a `ScrollView`.

The `ScrollView` resides in a `Grid` and it's `Height` is 700.

When I fill the `Label` with say, 5 lines of text its `Height` is 250.

```xml
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,4,0,4" Padding="0,4,0,4" VerticalOptions="Fill" Scrolled="sv_Scrolled">
    <Label x:Name="label" TextType="Html" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="16,0,16,0" Padding="30,4,30,4" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
</ScrollView>
```

How can I get the `Label` to fill the height of the `ScrollView`?

The reason I wish to do so is I'd like the blue `BackgroundColor` to fill the entire height of the `ScrollView`.

In Android this is not a problem, but with iOS the height stays stubbornly at 250, even if I set:

```cs
label.HeightRequest = 700;
label.MinimumHeightRequest = 700;
```

Any ideas on this?

**--UPDATE--**

I have partially solved this by extending the bottom padding of the label to make up the gap in height and fixes the color problem.

My problem is now when the label size increases to be greater than the ScrollView height, and I don't need the extra padding anymore so I remove it, the ScrollView doesn't resize and the gap remains.

I've tried:

```
scrollView.ForceLayout
scrollViewRenderer.SetNeedsLayout()
scrollViewRenderer.SetNeedsDisplay()
```

None work. Any ideas again?

Comment: Maybe you can use metrics. ` // Get Metrics
            var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
           //WIDTH
            var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;
            //HEIGHT
            var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
            // Screen density
            var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;`

Comment: Hey Mert, thanks for your reply. Not sure what you mean by this. It doesn't matter if I set the Label to 100, 1000 or screen height, it simply doesn't change.

Comment: Have you ever tried using Absolute Layout in scrollview ? Your parameteres of view are so certain.

Comment: Unfortunately may parameters change a lot. The label content changes constantly, so the height of both controls always need resizing.

Comment: Can you show the image about the result you want and you get? I can't understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Label to provide the ScrollView with a background color, you can simply set the `BackgroundColor` of the ScrollView directly to achieve what you want *(provided that I understand your requirement correctly)*:

```xml
<ScrollView
    BackgroundColor="Blue"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="0,4"
    Padding="0,4"
    VerticalOptions="Fill"
    Scrolled="sv_Scrolled">

    <Label
        x:Name="label"
        TextType="Html"
        Margin="16,0"
        Padding="30,4"
        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
        VerticalOptions="Fill"/>

</ScrollView>
```

If you need a gap between the ScrollView and the background color, you can also place the Label inside of a Grid and then set the background color of the Grid:

```xml
<ScrollView
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="0,4"
    Padding="0,4"
    VerticalOptions="Fill"
    Scrolled="sv_Scrolled">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue">

        <Label
            x:Name="label"
            TextType="Html"
            Margin="16,0"
            Padding="30,4"
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"/>

    </Grid>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi Julian, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that doesn't work, as I need padding in the `ScrollView` and a margin on the `Label`. Both will affect how and where the color appears.

Comment: @jho That wasn't entirely clear from the question, make sure that important details are clear. I've updated my question, you can wrap the Label in a Grid to provide the required padding.

Comment: Thanks again Julian. Would be prefer not to go down the Grid route because the Label and the ScrollView are resizable with label text content. I'd be concerned that adding a Grid would complicate the mechanics of that, and could potentially introduce unpredictable behaviour in either iOS or the Android side. I'm hoping I can find a way to simply force the height on just the label itself, but can't get that to work.

Comment: I don't think that the Label control is designed for that use case.